# Regex to Find URLs with only one slash

Tags: regex, url

I am testing a website and need to target the pages I want to include in the test with Regex.

I will be targeting only product pages which all have a single slash in the URL (The URLs do not show `http://` in them).

Here are the URLs I need to match:

The ones I want look like this:

```
www.example.com/just-one-slash
```

The ones I don't want look like this:

```
www.example.com/more-than-one/slash
www.example.com
```

Comment: How about: `www.mysite.com/just-on-slash/` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Do you want this regex to find `www.mysite.com/just-on-slash/` URL or not? Also let me know on which platform you want this regex?

Comment: You don't need a regex to count the number of slashes in a string.

Comment: The URL structure has no trailing slash.

Comment: The Regex is to applied through the testing tool.  It has to be "vanilla" Regex, as we do not know what is beneth the interface.

Comment: To help everyone understand the interface I have to apply the logic I need.  Here is a screen capture. http://awesomescreenshot.com/03b16h7e1e

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your case: `^[^/]+/?[^/]+$`

For the answer to be generic, with a trailing slash it would just need `/?` at the end, like this:  `^[^/]+/?[^/]+/?$`

Comment: Almost!  It will also target the homepage which has no slashes at all.  Thank YOU!

Comment: @user2295533 You're welcome. I've edited the regexp to match also the strings not having a slash inside.

Comment: Ok,here is what I get.  Can we exclude the homepage (no slashes) as well?  If not, I can always uses a 2nd case to exclude the homepage, so no biggie.    http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f816hcv9a

Comment: @user2295533 Could you give me an example of what do you mean by excluding the homepage, please?

Comment: @user2295533 Do you mean having a match `just-on-slash` after applying the regexp to `www.mysite.com/just-on-slash`?